# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, dynamic-programming

I'm new to C++ (as will be apparent from my code) and I'm practicing dynamic memory allocation with pointers and arrays, as well as my structures. My code works fine until it accesses the "growArray" function and then it gives me the SIGSEGV error. I can't figure out why though because as far as I can tell I'm passing a pointer to a pointer correctly, and I also allocate space for a new pointer. Is the problem with my structure, or is the problem with passing the pointer, or is the problem with receiving the pointer? I hope the question makes sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct FriendInfo
{
  string name;
  string address;
  string number;
};

FriendInfo *growArray(FriendInfo *p_entry, int *size);

int main()
{
    int curNum = 0;
    int size = 2;
    int userAnswer;
    FriendInfo *p_friends = new FriendInfo[size];

    cout << "Enter a friend's info?(1 for yes, 0 for no)\n";
    cin  >> userAnswer;
    while (userAnswer != 0)
    {
        if (curNum == size)
        {
            p_friends = growArray (p_friends, &size);
        }
        cout << "What is your friend's name?\n";
        cin  >> p_friends[curNum].name;
        cout << "What is your friend's address?\n";
        cin  >> p_friends[curNum].address;
        cout << "What is your friend's number?\n";
        cin  >> p_friends[curNum].number;
        curNum++;
        cout << "Enter another friend? (1 for yes, 0 for no)\n";
        cin  >> userAnswer;
    }
}

FriendInfo *growArray(FriendInfo *p_entry, int *size)
{
    *size *= 2;
    FriendInfo *p_new_friends = new FriendInfo[*size];
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; ++i)
    {
        p_new_friends[i] = p_entry[i];
    }
    delete [] p_entry;
    return p_new_friends;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory question --  Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Because he's training how to drive on manual?

Comment: He did specifically say that he's practicing DMA :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doubling the value of `size`, even though `p_entry` is of the initial `size`. Update the code to this:

```
FriendInfo *growArray(FriendInfo *p_entry, int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size * 2;
    FriendInfo *p_new_friends = new FriendInfo[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; ++i)
    {
        p_new_friends[i] = p_entry[i];
    }
    delete [] p_entry;
    *size = newSize;
    return p_new_friends;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you want to stop once you've reached the size of p_entry, not size

```
FriendInfo *growArray(FriendInfo *p_entry, int *size)
{
    int orig_size = *size;
    *size *= 2;
    FriendInfo *p_new_friends = new FriendInfo[*size];
    for (int i = 0; i < orig_size; ++i)
    {
        p_new_friends[i] = p_entry[i];
    }
    delete [] p_entry;
    return p_new_friends;
}
```